# How to tell if a specific Google Group is moderated?

Tags: google-groups

I posted a message to a google-group that I am a member of (web2py-users) about four hours ago and it has not shown up in the list of posts.  Thinking that I accidentally closed the tab before submitting my post, I reposted the same question.  My reposted question has not shown up either.

I don't believe this group was moderated in the past but it has been several months since I last posted.  I'm trying to find a "Group Information" page or similar which will tell me whether the group is moderated.  Does such a page exist?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To know if the group is moderated:

1. Go up from the topic until you see the group web page (i.e. the page with the list of the topics)
2. Click in the upper right **About** link (next to Members if you're logged).
3. The **Group Information** page opens. On the **Access** row (above Statistics) you will see **All posts are held for moderation** text if the group is moderated.